# Certificate not Visible in Keychain Import - HTTPs local server (Chrome/OS)

Tags: macos, ssl, https

I am trying to create a local HTTPS server to develop a webapp. Following [these instructions](https://github.com/lwsjs/local-web-server/wiki/How-to-get-the-%22green-padlock%22-using-the-built-in-certificate), I am only able to see `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/local-web-server/node_modules/lws/ssl/lws-cert.pem` by searching for

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/local-web-server/node_modules/lws/ssl
```

in the command line, and hitting `ls`. The file is not finable using the search function in Finder.

When going to Keychain to import the certificate, I cannot find it through searching Keychain or searching the import window. I have no idea how to import the file into Keychain via Terminal.

I have also tried to set up the server using [these instructions](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec), but am having the same issues as when I just ran `ws --https` - that is to say that Chrome refuses access to the webpage I am trying to run due to security issues.

Does anyone have any experience with a disappearing certificate in Mac OS? Is it possible to set up an HTTPS local server for Chrome on a Mac, or is this a dead dream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotlight search (which the Finder uses) intentionally omits system and invisible files; most people are just interested in their own documents, so it focuses on those. You can modify the search criteria to include system and/or invisible files (see [this Lifehacker article](https://lifehacker.com/5711409/how-to-search-for-hidden-packaged-and-system-files-in-os-x)), but in this case you already know where the file is, so you might as well just tell the computer where to find it. There are several ways to do this:

- In the Keychain Access import dialog, press Command-Shift-G, then type or paste in the path to the folder ("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/local-web-server/node_modules/lws/ssl"), select the file, and click Open.
- In the Finder, press Command-Shift-G, type or paste the path, then drag the file from the Finder window to the Keychain Access Import dialog.
- In Terminal, use the command `open /usr/local/lib/node_modules/local-web-server/node_modules/lws/ssl` to open the folder in Finder, then drag-and-drop as above.

Comment: Thanks! Second item worked like a charm. Only comment is that Command-Shift-G doesn't work in Keychain for me, and typing `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/local-web-server/node_modules/lws/ssl` into Terminal and pressing enter results in an error that that is a directory.

Comment: Oops, I goofed the Terminal command. It should be the command `open`, with the path as an argument to it. I've corrected it above. Anyway, glad you got it sorted!